# ITMS-90626: Invalid Siri Support - No example phrase was provided for INSearchForMessagesIntent in the 'en' language

Tags: ios, xcode

After I setup my intent for my widgetkit, i keep getting this warning every time i push my app to the appstore testflight.

`ITMS-90626: Invalid Siri Support - No example phrase was provided for INSearchForMessagesIntent in the 'en' language.`

`ITMS-90626: Invalid Siri Support - No example phrase was provided for INSearchForMessagesIntent in the 'en' language.`

`ITMS-90626: Invalid Siri Support - No example phrase was provided for INSearchForMessagesIntent in the 'en' language.`

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: hello have you find the solution yet?